# Grundy's game extended to more than two heaps

Tags: algorithm, theory, combinatorics, game-theory

How can In break a heap into two heaps in the Grundy's game?

What about breaking a heap into any number of heaps (no two of them being equal)?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791406/grundys-game-dividing-a-pile-into-two-unequal-piles

Comment: @amit That's my own question. But thanks for considering.

Comment: I know it is, I am posting it so answeres will be more likely to provide the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Games of this type are analyzed in great detail in the book series "[Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811306)". Most of the things you are looking for are probably in volume 1.

You can also take a look at these links: [Nimbers (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber), [Sprague-Grundy theorem (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) or do a search for "combinatorial game theory".

My knowledge on this is quite rusty, so I'm afraid I can't help you myself with this specific problem. My excuses if you were already aware of everything I linked.

**Edit:** In general, the method of solving these types of games is to "build up" stack sizes. So start with a stack of 1 and decide who wins with optimal play. Then do the same for a stack of 2, which can be split into 1 & 1. The move on to 3, which can be split into 1 & 2. Same for 4 (here it gets trickier): 3 & 1 or 2 & 2, using the Spague-Grundy theorem & the algebraic rules for nimbers, you can calculate who will win. Keep going until you reach the stack size for which you need to know the answer.

**Edit 2:** The website I was talking about in the comments seems to be down. Here is a link of a backup of it: [Wayback Machine - Introduction to Combinatorial Games](http://web.archive.org/web/20100918035609/http://sps.nus.edu.sg/~limchuwe/cgt/).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will check the book. I have already checked the Wiki links.

Comment: Actually, it would be really helpful if you provide me with complete algorithm or some link which implements or explains it completely. It is hard to get this way. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: I once found a website that explained it quite nicely, but can't seem to find it anymore. I'll check my bookmarks at home when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Grundy's Game, and many games like it, can be solved with an algorithm like this:

```
//returns a Move object representing the current player's optimal move, or null if the player has no chance of winning
function bestMove(GameState g){
    for each (move in g.possibleMoves()){
        nextState = g.applyMove(move)
        if (bestMove(nextState) == null){
            //the next player's best move is null, so if we take this move, 
            //he has no chance of winning. This is good for us!
            return move;
        }
    }

    //none of our possible moves led to a winning strategy.
    //We have no chance of winning. This is bad for us :-(
    return null;
}
```

Implementations of GameState and Move depend on the game. For Grundy's game, both are simple.

`GameState` stores a list of integers, representing the size of each heap in the game.

`Move` stores an `initialHeapSize` integer, and a `resultingHeapSizes` list of integers.

`GameState::possibleMoves` iterates through its heap size list, and determines the legal divisions for each one.

`GameState::applyMove(Move)` returns a copy of the GameState, except the move given to it is applied to the board.

---

`GameState::possibleMoves` can be implemented for "classic" Grundy's Game like so:

```
function possibleMoves(GameState g){
    moves = []
    for each (heapSize in g.heapSizes){
        for each (resultingHeaps in possibleDivisions(heapSize)){
            Move m = new Move(heapSize, resultingHeaps)
            moves.append(m)
        }
    }
    return moves
}

function possibleDivisions(int heapSize){
    divisions = []
    for(int leftPileSize = 1; leftPileSize < heapSize; leftPileSize++){
        int rightPileSize = heapSize - leftPileSize
        if (leftPileSize != rightPileSize){
            divisions.append([leftPileSize, rightPileSize])
        }
    }
    return divisions
}
```

Modifying this to use the "divide into any number of unequal piles" rule is just a matter of changing the implementation of `possibleDivisions`.

---

I haven't calculated it exactly, but an unoptimized bestMove has a pretty crazy worst-case runtime. Once you start giving it a starting state of around 12 stones, you'll get long wait times. So you should implement [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to improve performance.

For best results, keep each GameState's heap size list sorted, and discard any heaps of size 2 or 1.

Comment: Sorry to ask you but, is this your own algorithm or did you find it somewhere? (no offense)

Comment: bestMove is a simplified version of the [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) algorithm, where this one has no maximum search depth or heuristic evaluation function. possibleDivisions, I just made up.

Comment: Actually,I was asking because there is a better way to solve it if you know Grundy values for some numbers initially. I know them for first 60 natural numbers. Now, the point is that it can be solved by directly looking at the initial situation(as we have knowledge). So, I am looking for the exact formula. Otherwise, this method is always true. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you implement memoization for bestMove, you can seed the function's answer dictionary with your 60 already known answers. But even if you don't, the algorithm will work properly - it doesn't always return true. For example, bestMove([2]) returns null because there are no possible moves for [2], so it skips the loop entirely.

Comment: Actually, the algorithm you have provided me was known to me as I have solved this kind of problem before. But the reason why I was looking for a shortcut was that I was facing problem in dividing a heap into any number of heaps. In your code, it is the function possible divisions. It is a bit easy to divide into 2 heaps of unequal size but I was facing difficulty in writing it for any number of divisions. It would be really nice if you could help me in doing that. Or you could just provide me the algorithm/pseudocode for doing that. Thanks

Comment: And as a suggestion you can optimize your possible divisions by first checking if the heap size is even/odd. Thus, you need to compare only when its even and that too can be avoided by using two loops, just skipping the condition when leftheapsize is equal to originalheapsize/2 .

Comment: For dividing into any number of heaps, you could get the [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of the heap size, and filter out any that have a repeated number.